# Save FCM Push Notification as Messages in Fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my first question. I have connected my domain into firebase. The push notification is working when I update the post in my Wordpress Blog. Ok, thats good for now. But, i want to save all that notification in a Fragment, and can be clicked from there to start an activity for post id. How to save that Notification?
Here is my Firebase Messaging code:

```
private static int VIBRATION_TIME = 500; // in millisecond
private SharedPref sharedPref;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
    if (sharedPref.getNotification()) {
        // play vibration
        if (sharedPref.getVibration()) {
            ((Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VIBRATION_TIME);
        }
        RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(sharedPref.getRingtone())).play();

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            FcmNotif fcmNotif = new FcmNotif();
            fcmNotif.setTitle(data.get("title"));
            fcmNotif.setContent(data.get("content"));
            fcmNotif.setPost_id(Integer.parseInt(data.get("post_id")));
            displayNotificationIntent(fcmNotif);
        }
    }
}

private void displayNotificationIntent(FcmNotif fcmNotif) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySplash.class);
    if (fcmNotif.getPost_id() != -1) {
        intent = new Intent(this, ActivityPostDetails.class);
        Post post = new Post();
        post.title = fcmNotif.getTitle();
        post.id = fcmNotif.getPost_id();
        boolean from_notif = !ActivityMain.active;
        intent.putExtra(ActivityPostDetails.EXTRA_OBJC, post);
        intent.putExtra(ActivityPostDetails.EXTRA_NOTIF, from_notif);
    }
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(fcmNotif.getTitle());
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(fcmNotif.getContent()));
    builder.setContentText(fcmNotif.getContent());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int unique_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    notificationManager.notify(unique_id, builder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can store the your Notification payload in database and create list in fragment and show data from Database and click on any row start activity according to Post ID by  getting post id by position

Comment: I have search the code in a google to make a fragment for Notifications. But there is a chat application that have user registered. My App doesnt support register/login, how to store notification payload in database and how to create list in fragment to show that data?

Comment: hi , here is no needs to user login and register . you can simply store your payload in the database and after stored data you can easily make list and just  make click event on list and get id according to clicked position. but if u want according to user and you don't have user login/Register then simply generate the random user id at a time when user installed app first time and work as you want as your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can save notification message when the notificaton arrived inside

> onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)

method like this

A full example of a notification is like this..

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    try {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String value1 = data.get("key_1");
        String value2 = data.get("key_2");
        String title=data.get("title");
        String msg=data.get("body");
        Log.d("Backgraound", value1);
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        sendNotification(title,msg,value1,value2);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Error Line Number",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody, String val1,String val2) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification_activity.class);
        //Bundle bundle = getApplicationContext().getExtras();
        Bundle basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key_1", val1);
        basket.putString("key_2", val2);
        intent.putExtras(basket);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.spacebar_round)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setColor( getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                                R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Error Line Number",Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That code is for saving notification in a notification center, right? I was able to save my notification in notification center. Now i want to save notification in a fragment. And can be used later when user delete the notification in a notification center..

Comment: use shared preference inside onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) method

Comment: I have added the sharedPref in my MessagingServices. Now, how to add the fragment to show the all notifications from that sharedpreferences?

Comment: Inside onCreateview() method from your desire fragment you restore your sharedPref database and display in view like recyclerview/listview

Comment: Its like I don't have database configuration in my firebase project. Don't understand about it. Its automaticaly create a database if I have new post there? Please help me. this is a code to show database in a tutorial. private void getPostinf(ImageView imageView, TextView post_title, String post_id) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("post_title").child("post_id");

Comment: and now how to sync it with my class?

Comment: First of all, You need messaging function with Notification or just real time database with notification or normal? you are confusing me .. Clear the question

Comment: Ok. Im sorry for my mistakes. So, dont away from here. First, i have setting the firebase account with a fcm API key and i have stored my api key to my wordpress blogm and notification is working. Notifcation is only show in my notification center, now i want to show it from fragment. I don't have a database in my firebase, i just have a API key to use in my wordpress. I don't understand how to make database in firebase, and how to send my notification to there and stored into my notification fragment.

Comment: You want show notification list inside fragment right?
if yes, when notification has arrived inside onMessageReceived() method you should save data in sharedpref and when user open the notification activity you should restore sharedpred and sow them in listview..

Comment: Another way doing this, When user click into notification you should redirect your fragment where recyclerview works with firebase. It is simple and easy.. am i clear?

Comment: The problem is, I don't have enough skill to make recycleview work with firebase, I post the firebase messaging services code in the question, how to make it works with recycleview? please give me a code..